# How do I choose an object in Java to change its fields?

Tags: java

> A theatre has spotlights mounted over its stage. Each spotlight can be on, off, or dimmed. Write a class called Spotlight to represent a spotlight. The class should have one field variable, status, to store the spotlight's status ( on, off, or dimmed). As well as a constructor, your class should contain the following methods:
>
> 1. `isOff()` returns true if the spotlight is off, false otherwise
> 2. `isOn()` returns true if the spotlight is on, false otherwise
> 3. `isDimmed()` returns true if the spotlight is dimmed, otherwise false
> 4. `on()` turns the spotlight on
> 5. `off()` turns the spotlight off
> 6. `dim()` dims the spotlight
> 7. `toString` returns the information about the spotlight as a String.

So this is my class and what I have so far:

```
class Spotlight
{
    private String status; //the status of the spotlight


    
    //constructor
    public Spotlight(String s)
    {
        status = s;
    }
    
    //get the spotlights status
    public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    //set the spotlights status
    public void setStatus(String newS)
    {
        status = newS;
    }

    //method to show that the spotlight is off
    public boolean isOff()
    {
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Off"))
           
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
             
       
    }

    //method to show that the spotlight is on
    public boolean isOn()
    {
             if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("On"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
       
    }

    //method to show that the spotlight is dimmed
    public boolean isDimmed()
    {
              return false;
       
    }

    //method to show that the spotlight is off
    public boolean on()
    {
              if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("On"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
       
    }

    //method to show that the spotlight is off
    public boolean off()
    {
              if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Off"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
       
    }

    //method to show that the spotlight is off
    public boolean dim()
    {
              return false;
       
    }
    

    //return all the information about the employee as a String
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Status: " + this.getStatus(); 
    }
    
}


       Spotlight a = new Spotlight("Off");
       Spotlight b = new Spotlight("Off");
       Spotlight c = new Spotlight("Off");
       Spotlight d = new Spotlight("Off");
       Spotlight e = new Spotlight("Off");


        //print out the information about them 
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println(a.toString());
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println(b.toString());
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println(c.toString());
           System.out.println(); 
           System.out.println(d.toString());
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println(e.toString());
           System.out.println(); 
       
           System.out.println("Select a light to turn on a-e");
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           String input = sc.nextLine();
           Spotlight f = new Spotlight(input);
```

So far I am able to change the status of the spotlight and let it display my results but if I am using for example twenty spotlight objects how can I choose which light I want to turn on?

Comment: If you're asking about code, put that code in your question. It seems you're new. Please take the tour and read the help center to understand how to ask a good question (and generally how to use Stack Overflow).

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking right now. If you have a reference to a `Spotlight` object, you can invoke its methods.

Comment: I put up all the code. What I am asking is that I created twenty objects which are the spotlights. They are all turned off and I want to be able to type On through the scanner and then lets say spotlight c turns on.

Comment: You must be storing the spotlights in some sort of collection. Find the appropriate one and invoke a corresponding method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way:

```
List<SpotLight> spotlights = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    spotlights.add(new SpotLight("Off"));

int choice = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Select a light to turn on 1-20");
    choice = sc.nextInt();
} while(choice < 1 || choice > 20);

spotlights.get(choice - 1).on();

System.out.println(spotlights);
```

---

See also documentation on [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

---

As a side note, you should really have your spotlight class use an `enum` instead of those strings:

```
public class SpotLight {     
    public enum State {
        On,
        Off,
        Dimmed
    }

    private State state;

    public SpotLight(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, for instance, create a spotlight with:

```
SpotLight spotlight = new SpotLight(SpotLight.State.Off);
```

Comment: @Tom Sorry I forgot a closing brace after the do-while loop. Try it again?

Comment: Sorry. Ok its showing up but when I pick an number it shows all the lights as off.

Comment: @Tom Hmm, I tested it myself and it works. Maybe the fault  is in your ```toString``` method? Here is my working code: [Link](https://ideone.com/Ujq2cT)